# Using clearInterval within a function to clear a setInterval on another function

Tags: javascript, settimeout, intervals

I think im missing something fairly obvious with how the clearInterval method works.

So with the code below. I would expect the first function call to execute testFunction and set the interval to repeat the function. The 2nd call would execute the second function which will remove the interval from the 1st function. As this would execute far before the 5000ms interval the first function would not be executed again. However it does not behave like this.

Could someone please explain what is wrong with my method?

Reason for this is in a program I am writing I am making repeated get requests, every 30 seconds or so , using setTimeout but i would like a method to easily remove this interval at other points in the program

```
function testFunction() {
    $("#test").append("test");
setTimeout(testFunction, 5000);
}
function stopFunction() {
    clearTimeout(testFunction);
}
testFunction();
stopFunction();
```

Comment: Read the docs for `clearTimeout`. It doesn't take a function, it takes an identifier for the timer - the same identifier that `setTimeout` returns, but you just casually discard without saving it to a variable. `timer = setTimeout(doSomething,time); clearTimeout(timer);`.

Comment: ahhhhhh. That makes perfect sense, thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout returns an ID so you should

```
var timeoutID = setTimeout(blah blah);
clearTimeout(timeoutID);
```

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout returns an object that you need to pass into the clearTimeout method. See this article for an example: http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` returns an identifier for the timer. Store this in a variable like:

```
var timeout;
function testFunction(){
  ...
  timeout = setTimeout(testFunction, 5000);
}
function stopFunction(){
  clearTimeout(timeout);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple and I think better  implementation for this .

```
var _timer = null,
    _interval = 5000,
    inProgress = false,
    failures = 0,
    MAX_FAILURES = 3;

function _update() {
    // do request here, call _onResolve if no errors , and _onReject if errors
}

function _start() {
    inProgress = true;
    _update();
    _timer = setInterval(_update, _interval);
}

function _end() {
    inProgress = false;
    clearInterval(_timer);
}

function _onReject(err) {
    if (failures >= MAX_FAILURES) {
        _end();
        return false;
    }
    _end();
    failures++;
    _start();
}

function _onResolve(response) {
    return true;
}
```

Comment: If you do http request , you need to think about http errors too.